# tablelayout getchildat scroll to that child

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout, layout-inflater

I actually trying something quite straightforward, however android and java are making my life not easy. The idea is to scroll to a specified child in the table layout.

I am using a Layoutinflater to add the entries to the table layout like the following :

```
     TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout3);  

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
     View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_news, null);  

     TextView firstname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);   
     firstname.setText(FN + " " + iLN);

     TextView date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);   
     date.setText(newPD);

     TextView post = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvpost);   
     post.setText(c.getString(iP));
     post.setFocusable(true);

     tl.addView(itemView, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I tried to use the getChildAt() for the tablelayout and I do get the child, however when I use the child it returns for everything "0".

Example Code:

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) tl.getChildAt(1);
TextView tv = (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
tv.requestFocus();
Log.w("news", Integer.toString(tv.getHeight()));
```

For the TextView Height it returns "0" eventhough it contains multiple lines and the requestfocus() does not work either.

So how can I scroll to the child in the table layout?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code sample doesn't work because you probably use it in the `onCreate` method and at that time the UI isn't drawn yet so the views don't have any dimensions. If this is the case you could simply post a `Runnable` on one of your views to delay a bit the dimensions gathering until after the `onCreate` method like this:

```
// post the Runnable
tl.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) tl.getChildAt(1);
                            // get the top position relative to the parent  
            int top = tr.getTop();
                            // scroll to that top position the wrapping ScrollView 
            sv.scrollTo(0, top);                
        }

    });
```

There is something strange about your code(from my point of view), if the code above doesn't work you should post more details about your layout files and use scenario.

Comment: As soon as the 22 hours are passed, I will award you the +50 reputation points.